# How to stream video using html 5 video element

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video

I'm trying to create a video banner similar to http://bkwld.com/, using the HTML 5  element.

On my website, the video only starts playing after the entire file is downloaded. Compare this to BKWLD (http://bkwld.com/), theirs starts playing as soon as the browser has downloaded the first few frames, and will then continue to stream.

How do I achieve this streaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify content-type.  If mp4 (and mov I believe) you can move the moov atom to the front of the video.  I use ffmpeg for this.

ffmpeg -y -i "#{infile}" -movflags faststart -codec:v copy -codec:a copy "#{outfile}"

this is typically very fast as it does not video or audio translation.

HTH,
Dan